# Terminology: a generalization of metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, terminology

How is it called the generalization of metric spaces with only the following axioms?

- $d(x,x)=0$
- $d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)$

Note that most probably I will need $d$ to be a function to $\mathbb{R}_{+}\cup\{\infty\}$.

Comment: 0 = d(x,x) <= d(x,x) + d(x,y) = d(x,y) validates your concern.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I don't understand you: 1. Is `<=` implication? inequiality? 2. What do you mean by "validates"?

Comment: See my edit in the answer below where I repeat the point made by @WilliamElliot: the axioms imply positivity.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @HennoBrandsma! It didn't cross my mind to explain the nomenclature for some reason

Comment: Why allow $+\infty$ as a value? Then taking open balls, we get some parts of the space that are "unreachable" from each other (we get disjoint sums, maybe).

Comment: $+\infty$ is very necessary, otherwise distance is undefined between a set an empty set. If you want details, get this book: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B081GCFRHZ/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&linkCode=sl1&tag=porton-20&linkId=37c70a0c54bfdd159b2543736c7932a5&language=en_US

Comment: That's only if you *want* to define that distance. And such spaces (with this generalised distance in ordered semigroups) have been introduced a long time ago.  As a student I already saw a talk "all spaces are metric" using just such ideas (way back in the 90's). So the book idea is far from new, it's old hat.

Comment: No, it isn't "generalised distance in ordered semigroups", it is ordered semigroup of generalized distances. So you misunderstood. My idea is new. It revealed to me through te stage of first defining and researching _funcoids_: https://mathematics21.org/algebraic-general-topology-and-math-synthesis/ - funcoids is a previously unknown thing and their research opens door to big news - _algebraic_ general topology, a wide generalization of general topology. That was unknown.

Comment: @porton you might also be interested in Lawvere metric spaces, which are pseudo-quasimetric spaces, but are additionally allowed to have distance infinity. See https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/metric+space for details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems such an object is called a [quasi-pseudometric](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/cjm/2014/198685/)

(A pseudometric is a metric that allows $d(x,y)=0$ for some $x \neq y$, a quasimetric is a metric that needs not be symmetric; this combination lets go of both).

The function always has values $\ge 0$, as for $x,y$ we have
$$0 = d(x,x) \le d(x,x)+d(x,y)=d(x,y)$$

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: To add to your summary in parentheses, the typical usage is *pseudo* allows different points to have a zero distance, *quasi* allows symmetry to fail, and *semi* allows the triangle inequality to fail. However, one needs to watch for context, as this usage by general topologists differs from that used by functional analysts, where for example metrics obtained from [seminorms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Seminorm.html) are pseudometrics and not semimetrics (appropriate natural language quantification being used here).